# Why is my iOS widget so tall?

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, today-extension

It looks fine in the Storyboard interface:

[image]

However, in the actual notification center, there's a bunch of space below my two views that ends up filling the height of the screen:

[image]

Why?

Comment: Could you post *some* code, or is this bare-bones storyboard work? I remember having the same problem back when they released today extensions, but the client dropped the feature, so I didn't fix it, as far as I remember

Comment: It's all in Storyboard -- I have no code that does anything with layout. :-( Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Today Extension doesn't know how tall it should be. Give something in your Storyboard a static height, like your info `UIButton`, and set its top and bottom pins.

For example, `infoButton Height Equals: 20`, `infoButton Bottom Space: Bottom Layout Guide Equals: 8`, `infoButton Top Space: Top Layout Guide Equals: 8`.

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure that's it-- or I can't figure out how to set the constraints properly. I've tried everything with constraints (and "Adjust Frames" too) and nothing seems to make it smaller.

Comment: Ended up being able to get it to work once I figured out how to constrain things to the bottom guide. Thanks for the tip!